# Understanding performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, segue

Can someone more knowledgeable than I explain `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` for me? I need to switch views (and classes) and also carry a few NSStrings and IDs over to that view's class. I was wondering if this is possible with `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

First, you have to have set up the segue in your storyboard **and give it the appropriate identifier**.  (Click on the segue (left panel) and then click on Attributes (right panel).

You can then link this to buttons or selection of table rows from your storyboard, or you can call it in code using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

After this, your view controller will be sent the `prepareForSegue:sender:` message. You override this method in your view controller subclass, and can configure the target view controller as follows:

```
TargetViewController *targetVC = (TargetViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
targetVC.string1 = string1;
```

And so forth. The `sender` in this method will be the object that you use as the `sender` in the original method call.

Comment: Thanks! That actually explained alot! :)

Comment: I did (Myclass *)nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
nextView.textfield1.text = @"Test";

but xcode has a problem with (Myclass *)nextViewController

Comment: MyClass has to be a subclass of UIViewController. Segues are for new view controllers, not views.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ment UIViewController, not views, sorry for confusion.

Comment: I get "Use of undeclared Identifier "nextViewController" so I gave the ViewController in the IB that identifier but it still says that :(

Comment: Sorry had the code in my answer wrong, typing on the phone! Please see updated code.

Comment: Thanks!! And no worries :-) Enjoy your iPhone! Don't have money to buy one... yet.

Comment: @jrturton , what's the difference between link this to buttons or selection of table rows OR call it in code using performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:? Thanks

Comment: @jrturton  I have a question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306589/nsobjectnsobject-doesnotrecognizeselector-crash-when-call-viewcontroller. It looks like I want to call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: programmatically, but prepareForSegue:sender: method still got called by some where else. Would you please advice some hint? Thanks.

Comment: If anybody was wondering how to create a segue in the storyboard check  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17012857/423646

Answer (score 9):

Most segues are initiated automatically as the result of some user interaction. For instance, if you have a segue that is wired up from a button to a scene in a storyboard, when the button is tapped the segue will automatically initiate.

Occasionally, it makes sense to trigger a segue programmatically - e.g. you have a High Scores scene that is displayed when the user wins a round of a game. There's no way to express the concept of winning in the storyboard itself, so you can instead create a segue, assign an identifier to it, and invoke `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` at runtime.

The other segue related method on UIViewController, `-prepareForSegue:sender:`, is the method you should override to perform any customization on the destination view controller.

Answer (score 3):

In `prepareForSegue:sender:` you get a chance to configure the `destinationViewController`: that's where you'd pass it the data it needs. It's discussed in [Cocoa Application Competencies for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link and info, I will read thru it. Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score -1):

Today I ran into the issue of performSegueWithIdentifier: not executing due to the fact of not having set a delegate queue on my URL session.

So by any chance, check if you are actually setting a delegate queue when creating your URLSession, else URLSession will create it's own.

```
urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfigObject
                                           delegate:self
                                      delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```

I mention this here because I quite often see URLSession handling ending up calling some sort of UI related activity. And performSegue needs to be executed on main, or else it will do just nothing.