# How do I add a segue to an UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, segue

I am building an app for the first time using Storyboards.  I have a scene which I would like to have open another scene when there is a long tap on a particular button.  I am able to add the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with no problem, but I can't figure out how to have that gesture be the segue to the other scene.  Doesn't seem to matter what I Ctrl-Drag, nothing works.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can control-drag from your first controller's window to your second controller to create the segue, and then you can call `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your `GestureRecognizer` method.

Comment: the problem here it loads the view again it doesnt retain the values inside.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18113316/1966109) to a similar question may also be useful as it gives more details to implement what you need.

Comment: thanks. worked for me as well. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176215/understanding-performseguewithidentifier) is a nice explanation of performSegueWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 4):

It's now possible to do it all in your Storyboard visually. Every gesture recognizer has Triggered Segues in Connections Inspector.

Comment: Actually It seems that you cant connect segue to long press in storyboard. Which personally I hate. I use it a lot to simulate highlight on big touchable objects and need add segue identifiers and performSegue...