# Hiding UIBarbuttonItem of navigationcontroller swift

Tags: swift2, uibarbuttonitem, swrevealviewcontroller

New to swift implemented sliding menu by learning from [swrevealviewcontroller swift](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)

now i want to hide the menu button i.e. UIBarButtonItem which opens the side menu.
I have searched found most of place following code:

```
menuBtn.enabled = false
```

but it only disables the button and not hide it.

Please let me know what wrong i am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the left button :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = false;
```