# Segue not working in coreplot Graphview.m after onclick barchart column

Tags: ios, ios6, core-plot

Using the code below in coreplot(Barchart) to perform segue from GraphView.m class

but I get an error:  `instance method '-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

How do I fix it ? Please Help .
Thanks in Advance.

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
        NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex %d", index);

         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"list2" sender:self];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GraphView.m  is a UIView you won't get very far, as `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` is a UIViewController method.

Assuming that graphView is created from a viewController, you want to set it's delegate to the viewController.

in GraphView.h

- declare a graphView protocol above your @interface:

  `@protocol GraphViewDelegate`
  `-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index`
   `@end`
- declare a property:

  `@property (weak) id <GraphViewDelegate> delegate;`

in GraphView.m:

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
        [[self delegate] barPlot:plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:index];
    }
```

in ViewController.h modify the @interface line

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <GraphViewDelegate>
```

in ViewController.m

- when you create the graphView, set the delegate to self (if graphView is created in Interface Builder, you can CTRL-drag a line to the viewController to set the delegate):

  `GraphView* graphView = [GraphView alloc] init];`
  `[graphView setDelegate:self];`
- implement the delegate method as you had it in GraphView (you may not need the `index` parameter but I carried it over anyway)..

  ```
  -(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
   {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"list2" sender:self];
   }
  ```

You probably want to modify your method signature, to something like

```
            -(void)graphView:(GraphView*)graphView 
         didSelectBarAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
                     barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot 

 (it's good practice to send a reference to the sender along with the message)
```

Comment: Graphview is just a class .So How do I **performSegueWithIdentifier:sender**  within the method shown above?

Comment: You really want to be sending it to your viewController - better still, use a delegate to message the viewController - does that make sense from the perspective of GraphView?

Comment: How to do that? Please help.

Comment: Is there a UIViewController that creates the graphView?

Comment: Thank You Sir. I tried **TargetViewController *targetVC = (TargetViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
targetVC.string1 = string1;** as suggested by Mr.Prajwal and its still not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22740/discussion-between-jacob-wood-and-he-was)

Answer (score 0):

the method is not found you can try also including that method in .h file if you are sure that you have not made any spelling mistake.

Comment: I have not made any spelling mistake.Its a class I am trying to call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender inside the method in that class How do I do that ?

Comment: may this would help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176215/understanding-performseguewithidentifier)