# Adding a separate identifier to a second dynamic cell in ios 6?

Tags: dynamic, uitableview, ios6, segue, identifier

The first scene of the project is a dynamic cell view, as shown below. I have given this an identifier so I can refernce it in the code.

[image: dynamic cells]

I have created a second grouped section from within the code which displays as expected. When a user clicks on the first cell it moves to one particular scene, however the second cell also goes to the same scene.

How can I give the second cell a separate identifier so I can then create a segue to a different scene? The second cell doesn't appear in the Storyboard so I can't give it one that way.

The code I have for this scene at the moment is below:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize testLocation;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    testLocation = @"Washington, Dulles";
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


#pragma mark - Table View Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;              // Default is 1 if not implemented
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;    // fixed font style. use custom view (UILabel) if you want something different

{
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Choose Test Location:";
    }
    else {
        return @"Choose Test Type:";
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{


    UITableViewCell *serverLocCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"serverLocation"];

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            serverLocCell.textLabel.text = testLocation;
            serverLocCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Change";
            break;
        case 1:
            serverLocCell.textLabel.text = @"Speed Test";
            serverLocCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Change";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return serverLocCell;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storyboard editor, create the two segues you want to use — but make them segue from one controller to the next, NOT from the table view. Do it at the controller level. Give each segue a specific and different name.

Implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so you know when the user selects a cell in the table. Depending on the section (or row) in the index path, programmatically fire the segue.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I have done as you say and will now source how to programatically fire the segue

Comment: Some hints here, Dan. Let me know if you need more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176215/understanding-performseguewithidentifier?rq=1