# Call method in other viewcontroller by notification when view appears

Tags: ios, nsnotification

I have two ViewControllers. Let's call them aVC and bVC.

In aVC, I show an alertView. If you press a Button on that alertView, a segue is performed to bVC.

In bVC, something should happen when the view appears but only when triggered from that button in aVC.

I tried notifications.

When pressed Button of alertView in aVC, notification is posted.  In viewDidLoad of bVC, I did addObserver for that notification, but this does not work.

I guess because the observer is added after post of the notification? That's only my guess.

I tried for hours to get that to work, but notifications does not seems to do the job.

So how can I call a method in bVC that is executed when the view appears triggered by that button of the alertview in aVC?

Comment: Sorry everyone, i am new here. Maybe it is a stupid question but why does my posts get corrected (capitalization and so on)? I thought this is the internet and not school ;) Please enlighten me !

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean property in bVC that defines whether bVC was loaded from the button in aVC or not. In `prepareForSegue:sender:`, set that property to true before you perform the segue (you can use `sender` to determine if the call came from your button), and in bVC, on appearance, check for said property.

An example on how to set such a property is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176361/886407.

Answer (score 0):

you can just call your method in viewDidLoad of bVC.

“When pressed Button of alertView in aVC, notification is posted. In viewDidLoad of bVC, I did addObserver for that notification, but this does not work”
just like you guess , the observer is added after post of the notification.

Comment: Thx, but the method in bVC should not been called everytime the bVC appears, so i can not just put it in viewDidLoad. it should be called only if invoked by that button in aVC. But thx anyways ;)

Comment: the viewDidLoad will not called everytime the bVC appears.

Comment: the viewDidLoad will call when the bVC is  first loaded.