# Segues in uitableView emebed in ViewController using swrevealviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm developing an iOS app and I have a big problem...

I need to have a tableview inside viewController (that's why I can not use UiTableViewController) and I can't use static cells. I solved that creating a NSMutableArray and loading each cell in my cellForRowAtIndexPath.

So, what's my problem?

In swrevealviewcontroller tutorials (like http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) they use segues for navigation when pushing cells, so, How can I create segues dinamically?

I tried to use

```
MyNewVC *myNewVc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewVc animated:YES];
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a generic segue and use that? It doesn't need to be connected to a cell or a UI control. That way your code will work as long as the segue identifier is correct.

Comment: But how can I do it? I only know how to create a segue in my storyboard, and that means, that I connect my prototype cell with one view controller, and I need 6 different view controllers

Comment: At the bottom of your screen / view controller in storyboard there is a yellow icon - ctrl + drag from there to another view controller. Give the segue an identifier. Then just repeat this step for all the other view controllers. Don't connect it to the cell

Comment: No problem. Accept the answer if it helped. It lets everyone else know which answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the segues from the view controller to their destinations then use the view controller's preformSegueWithIdentifier: method. See this: [Understanding performSegueWithIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176215/understanding-performseguewithidentifier)

Comment: I can`t do that. They are not static, soy in my view controller I only have 1 prototype cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self presentViewController:magnifiedVC animated:YES completion:^{
    //place block to run here, such as assigning properties
}];
```

It is not a segue, but another way of keeping track of view controllers. you can then dismiss the destination view controller by doing this in a destination view controller method:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This means you will have instantiate the destination view controller in your presenting view controller, which you do not need to with a segue I afaik.

EDIT1:
In that case, you can use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to allocate and prepare the view controller, and then use `performSegueWithIdentifier:`. you will then need to use core data or plists to store the state of each view controller everytime you perform a segue to prevent the sending controller from being unloaded and released and losing its data. you can do this in the `prepareForSegue:`.

note: you can not use storyboard instantiated view controllers for use on the navigation controller

Comment: Thanks!I didn't know that it was possible to do that. I think is really usefull for "about" views for example, but in my case,it is a bad programming practice because my tableview is a menu.
When my users push in a cell, they will navigate to another view whit the same tableviw, so if they navigate a lot, they will have multiple views one in front of each other