# What is proper to set as sender in performSegueWithIdentifier:sender?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, segue

Is it only view controllers (i.e.: do you typically only pass `self`)? Or could I pass the indexPath of a cell, or the UIButton that is causing the segue?

Comment: Have your read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176215/understanding-performseguewithidentifier ?

Comment: You can pass anything you like as `sender`

Comment: @Chiquis Yes. I fail to see anything there that answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you call this method programatically, (which is what you are doing), sender can have any OBJECT which will be used for informational purposes only. As the documentation states it:

> sender
>   The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This
>   object is made available for informational purposes during the actual
>   segue.

Which is found here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: